# how to call pure virtual function from base class if that function is defined in more than 2 derived class

Tags: c++

```
class Base
{

    public:
    void func();
    void pureFunc()=0;

};

void Base::func()
{

    pureFunc();

}
```

another file

```
#include "base.h"
class D1: public Base
{

    void pureFunc()
    {
    cout << "D1";
    }

};
```

in another file

```
#include "base.h"
class D2: public Base
{

    void pureFunc()
    {
    cout << "D2";
    }

};
```

which class's pureFunc is called in base class ?

Comment: You need to show how you are calling the virtual function.

Comment: there is no `virtual` in your code ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole point of pure virtual functions is to actually decouple the concrete implementation from the abstract base class interface.

If you are calling the `pureFunc()` through a `Base*` pointer or reference, the calling code should be agnostic about the implementations in `D1` and `D2`, and thus shouldn't need to know which one is actually called.

Answer (score 1):

The declaration should be **`virtual`**`void pureFunc()=0` for the `=0` to make sense.

Then it depends on which class you instantiate. If you create a `D2`:

```
D2 d2{};
```

then a `Base` pointer will call `D2::pureFunc()`, for example:

```
Base* bptr = &d2;
bptr->pureFunc(); // calls D2::pureFunc()
```

But if you had created the same pointer to a `D1` then the same call would resolve to `D1::pureFunc()`

```
D1 d1{};
bptr = &d1; // same pointer now points to a D1
bptr->pureFunc(); // now calls D1:pureFunc()
```